# Run batch file located in sub directory with another batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, subdirectory

So I know you think I should do something like: start C:\parentfolder\subfolder\batchfile.bat

or something along those but I was wonder if there was like a way to reference the sub directory without using it's actual name? Since the batch files will be generated by another batch file.

Don't ask why I need it to be generated I'd much rather it not but couldn't find any other way.

Comment: There is, they are called relative paths.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for your answer but it still did not solve my problem. I need my batch file to go into a folder below and run the batch file start.bat.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cd into a subdirectory and then run `start start.bat`. That should run another batch file. To go into a relative subdirectory, run the command `cd foldername`. You have to make sure you are currently in the parent directory.